# ¿Como eliminar numeros de un string en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola quiero eliminar los numeros que estan en un string y dejar solo letras, hice esto:

```
declare @string varchar(100)='1095djig2'
SELECT STUFF(@string, charindex(@string,48), len(@string)/*charindex(@string,57)*/, '');
```

Pero devuelve

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of stuff function.

Por lo que entendi el stuff elimina la posicion de un string y lo reemplaza por lo que se le agregue en el ultimo parametro, yo quiero hacerlo con codigo ascii , entonces lo que intento hacer es si @string contiene numero empezando la busqueda a partir del 0 (48 en codigo ascii) hasta 9 (57 codigo ascii) de ser asi que los borre y los remplace por ' ', no se como decirle que realice la busqueda hasta el 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff inserta una cadena en otra, no reemplaza caracteres. Con Stuff podrías eliminar la primera parte de la cadena, pero te quedaría colgado el 2 final. Aunque es posible, hacerlo, no parece tener mucho sentido, complicarse no obstante.

La opción más simple para eliminar caracteres numéricos es utilizar la función Replace

```
Declare @String VarChar(100) = '1095djig2';

Select REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(@String, '9', '')
                                    , '8', '')
                                , '7', '')
                            , '6', '')
                        , '5', '')
                    , '4', '')
                , '3', '')
            , '2', '')
        , '1', '')
    , '0', '');
```

Por tanto lo podrías simplificar con una función.

```
Create function dbo.reemplazarNumeros 
(
    @string varchar(max)
)
Returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
Return
(
Select REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(@String, '9', '')
                                    , '8', '')
                                , '7', '')
                            , '6', '')
                        , '5', '')
                    , '4', '')
                , '3', '')
            , '2', '')
        , '1', '')
    , '0', '')
    );
End;
GO
```

Y ahora, ya puedes utilizar la función.

```
declare @string varchar(100)='1095djig2';
Select dbo.reemplazarNumeros(@string);
```

[image: Resultado]

La opción que intentas, utilizando Stuff y PatIndex, y un bucle, lo puedes realizar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.reemplazarNumeros2(@String varchar(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos INT
  SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@String)
  WHILE @Pos > 0
   BEGIN
    SET @String = STUFF(@String,@pos,1,'')
    SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@String)
   END
  RETURN @String
END
GO
```

Y su consumo.

```
declare @string varchar(100)='1095djig2';
Select dbo.reemplazarNumeros2(@string);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]