# Restriccion de texto SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como aplico una restricción o un tipo de dato en "Autor" que no acepte valores numéricos?
Alguna sugerencia mas optima que hacer

"Constraint ck_Autor Check (Auto like '[A-Z][A-Z](45 VECES)')

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes primero plantear bien la pregunta [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) puedes ver como realizar la pregunta. Como segundo depende para que lo quieres realizar si es directamente en sql server puede utilizar una función para que elimine los números como [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406966/como-eliminar-numeros-de-un-string-en-sql-server) o si es desde código dependería del código que vas a implementar y si es de escritorio o web.

Answer (score 4):

Dos sugerencias. La primera y más importante, si quieres rendimiento olvídate de crear una columna [Text](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Además de estar en desuso la recomendación oficial es usar varchar o nvarchar.

Luego puedes utilizar una expresión o una función escalar para resolver la constraint.

```
Create Table libros
             (
             id    Int
             Primary Key Identity(1, 1)
           , autor NVarchar(45) Default N'Anónimo'
           , Constraint ck_autor Check(Case
                                           When autor Like '%[0-9]%' Then 1
                                       Else 0
                                       End = 0)
             );
```

Una opción, es un simple case que evalúa el contenido de la columna a insertar y si el mismo contiene un número entonces, case devuelve un 1 por tanto 1 = 0 no inserta.

O con la misma técnica, también te puedes crear una función escalar.

```
Create function [dbo].[CheckNoNumeric](
    @autor nvarchar(45)
    )
Returns bit
As
Begin
    return (Select case when @autor like '%[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) 
End
```

Ejemplos

```
Insert Into dbo.libros(autor)
Values
       ( 'ab' );

Insert Into dbo.libros(autor)
Values
       ( 'dasdfasd' );
```

Generan 2 rows

[image: Resultado]

Al igual que con la función.

```
Insert into dbo.librosConFuncionEscalar 
(autor)
values
('abc');
```

[image: Resultado2]

Pero si pones un número.

```
Insert Into dbo.libros(autor)
Values
       ( 'das3dfasd' );
go
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 23 Instrucción INSERT en conflicto
> con la restricción CHECK 'ck_Autor'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la
> base de datos 'HowTo', tabla 'dbo.Libros', column 'Autor'.

```
Insert into dbo.librosConFuncionEscalar(autor)
values
('ab1c');
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 14 Instrucción INSERT en conflicto
> con la restricción CHECK 'ck_autorCheckFunction'. El conflicto ha
> aparecido en la base de datos 'HowTo', tabla
> 'dbo.librosConFuncionEscalar', column 'autor'.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces una doble comparación en vez de hacer una más simple como `Check( autor NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' )`?

Comment: Si bien en la pregunta dice que no acepte valores numéricos, en su propuesta aplica la restricción a que contenga caracteres de la A a la Z. Me pareció que es más razonable adaptarme a sus conocimientos, porque me supongo que si sabe lo que significa eso. Además la carga computacional de hacer una a otra manera es infima y aunque insertase millones de filas no lo notaría y las posibilidades de reaprovechamiento son mucho mayores. Mañana le piden que acepte interrogantes....o...lo que sea, y puede adaptarlo con suma facilidad.

Comment: El problema es que el uso de CASE en condiciones es una mala práctica que lleva a evitar el uso de índices en las columnas. Y si realmente se desea una condición que solo acepte letras, lo ideal sería algo más restrictivo como `autor NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%'. Esa condición indica que la cadena no debe de tener ningún caracter diferente a letras. Se pueden incluir minúsculas si es una intercalación sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero eso de que CASE sea una mala práctica en una Constraint, no lo veo. Y en un índice, que existiese y fuera aprovechable por una supuesta consulta, es al menos igual de bueno que puede ser un LIKE %.